# How to set number of textview in horizontal scroll dynamically when data is coming from JSON parsing?

Tags: android, json

I am fetching the JSON data via URL and displaying it in text view inside the horizontal scroll view.

```
            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        ArrayList<Details> myModelList = new ArrayList<Details>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            mymodel = new Details();
                            mymodel.id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                            mymodel.url = jsonObject.getString("resLink");
                            mymodel.resType = jsonObject.getString("resType");
                            mymodel.name = jsonObject.getString("resName");

                            myModelList.add(mymodel);


                            setData(myModelList);
```

I am showing my data in text view but it shows the first data only

```
    private void setData(List<Details> mList) {
    for (int i =0; i <=mymodel.getResType().length();i++)
    {
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(mymodel.getResType());


}
```

Comment: Well, you're setting the same text for every i, what did you expect? `mymodel.getResType()` always returns the same thing as you're not changing the object `mymodel`. What are you iterating through? What's the for loop for? What's the `mymodel` object?

Comment: I am updating the question

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the mymodel in the for loop again and again so I think it contains only one value that too the last one(not the first one).

If that is the problem, try declaring the following outside the for loop.

mymodel = new Details();

Answer (score 0):

So there's quite a few problems in your code:

1) You are always replacing the text of the same `TextView`. Normally with scrolling views you back them up with an adapter, place your data into the list that is then added to the adapter, then rely on the scrolling list to dynamically create the `TextView` which you can populate. If you have a known number of views in your scroll view and you want to avoid adapters, make sure they all have unique IDs so that you could find them.

2) Second problem is you're calling your `setData` inside the loop. Finish the loop first, then call you method (although you won't really have to do this if you do the adapter thing)

3) Your `setData` method is all sorts of wrong. If you want to pass a list to a method then iterate through it, you do it like this:

```
    for (Details d : list) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(d.getResType());
    }
```

But like I said, that probably won't help you on its own. Look into documentation for the scroll lists or recycler view and adapters. There are many examples available around.